# How to describe the one-many relations in Coq?

Tags: math, logic, relation, coq, theorem-proving

I was reading the book Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy by B.Russell and trying to formalize all the theorems described in it.

One-many relations are described by the following text ([contexts on book](http://people.umass.edu/klement/imp/imp.html#page47)).

> One-many relations may be defined as relations such that, if x has the
> relation in question to y, there is no other term x' which also has
> the relation to y.
>
> Or, again, they may be defined as follows: Given
> two terms x and x', the terms to which x has the given relation and
> those to which x' has it have no member in common.
>
> Or, again, they may
> be defined as relations such that the relative product of one of them
> and its converse implies identity, where the “relative product” of two
> relations R and S is that relation which holds between x and z when
> there is an intermediate term y, such that x has the relation R to y
> and y has the relation S to z.

It poses three ways of definition. I've been successfully described the first two and proved their equivalence. While I was stuck on the third, I tried to get rid of the concepts of 'relative product' and directly get to its connotation but also failed.

Here below are my definitions, did I make any mistakes?

```
Definition one_many {X} (R : relation X) : Prop :=
  forall x y, R x y -> forall x', x <> x' -> ~(R x' y).

Definition one_many' {X} (R : relation X) : Prop :=
  forall x x' y, R x y -> R x' y -> x = x'.

Inductive relative_product
          {X} (R: relation X) (S: relation X) : relation X :=
  | rp0 : forall x y, forall z, R x y -> S y z -> relative_product R S x z.
Inductive converse {X} (R : relation X) : relation X :=
  | cv0 : forall x y, R x y -> converse R y x.
Inductive id {X} : relation X :=
  | id0 : forall x, id x x.

Definition one_many'' {X} (R : relation X) : Prop :=
  forall x y, relative_product R (converse R) x y <-> id x y.
```

Below is how I interpret the definition of the third and also I failed to prove their equivalence.

```
Goal forall {X} (R : relation X),
    one_many'' R <-> (forall x y, R x y -> forall x', converse R y x' -> x = x').
Proof.
  intros. unfold one_many''. split.

  intros.
  assert (relative_product R (converse R) x x' <-> id x x'). apply H.
  inversion H2. apply id_eqv. apply H3.
  apply rp0 with y. assumption. assumption.

  intros.
  split. intro.
  inversion H0. subst.
  apply id_eqv. apply H with y0.
  assumption. assumption.

   (* I'm stuck here. This subgoal is obviously not provable. *)
```

in which proof, `id_eqv` is `Lemma id_eqv : forall {X} (x:X) (y:X), x = y <-> id x y`, easily proved in advance.

Can somebody help me to figure out or give me a hint about where I went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define `relation`? Can you share rest of your definitions?

Comment: sinan: relation is directly taken from the standard library Relations, which is `Definition relation (X:Type) := X -> X -> Prop`.

Comment: Is `id_eqv` also defined in stdlib? I'm having trouble finding required definitions.

Comment: sinan: Sorry I'ved missed that. I proved `id_eqv` myself. `Lemma id_eqv : forall {X} (x:X) (y:X), x = y <-> id x y`.

Comment: Do you need `R x y <-> converse R y x` in your definition of the converse relation, or is it easy to prove `converse R y x -> R x y` given that definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've mistranslated the third definition.  The original text says:

> Or, again, they may be defined as relations such that the relative product of one of them and its converse **implies** identity

(emphasis mine).  That would translate as:

```
forall x y, relative_product R (converse R) x y -> id x y
```

That is, it should be a straight implication, rather than the equivalence you've asserted.  You can't hope to prove your third statement from either of the others, since it's not equivalent:  consider the empty relation on a nonempty set.  That's certainly a one-to-many relation, but the relative product with its converse is also empty, so is not the full identity relation.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, but you might need `R` to be reflexive or not empty. Using your script I end up having to prove

```
1 subgoal
X : Type
R : relation X
H : forall x y : X, R x y -> forall x' : X, converse R y x' -> x = x'
y : X
______________________________________(1/1)
relative_product R (converse R) y y
```

So you have a relation `R`, and one inhabitant `y:X`. To prove your goal, you need to have a witness `z` such that `R y z` and `R z y`. Without any other information, I guess your only shot is to have `R` to be reflexive and `z` be `y`.